# Difference of two logarithmic Gamma functions

Tags: logarithms, gamma-function

Deep within an MCMC algorithm, I need to evaluate this expression:

$$\log(\Gamma(x + c)) - \log(\Gamma(x + 1/2))$$

where $x$ is a variable, and $c$ is a constant such that $c\geq1/2$.

This expression will be evaluated millions of times, so I need to simplify/approximate it as much as possible with as little cost on its accurateness as possible.

Can this be done or is this as good as it gets?

Answer (score 3):

You are computing

$$ \int_{x+1/2}^{x+c}\psi(x)\,dx $$
where by Binet's second integral
$$ \psi(x) = \log(x)-\frac{1}{2x}-2\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{t\,dt}{(t^2+x^2)(e^{2\pi t}-1)}. $$
This leads to [Stirling's formula for $\log\Gamma$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation#Stirling's_formula_for_the_gamma_function), which can be used with a suitable number of terms, depending on the tolerated error.